# how to manage an NDC-like log4net stack with async/await methods? (per-Task stack?)

Tags: c#, logging, asynchronous, log4net, async-await

In a normal/synchronous/single-threaded console app, NDC.Push works fine for managing the 'current item' (potentially at multiple levels of nesting, but just 1 level for this example).

For example:

```
private static ILog s_logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Program");

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BasicConfigurator.Configure();

    DoSomeWork("chunk 1");
    DoSomeWork("chunk 2");
    DoSomeWork("chunk 3");
}

static void DoSomeWork(string chunkName)
{
    using (NDC.Push(chunkName))
    {
        s_logger.Info("Starting to do work");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        s_logger.Info("Finishing work");
    }
}
```

This will result in the expect log output, showing a 'chunk X' NDC entry just to the right of 'Program' (the default pattern for the basic configurator)

> 232 [9] INFO Program chunk 1 - Starting to do work
>
> 5279 [9] INFO Program chunk 1 - Finishing work
>
> 5279 [9] INFO Program chunk 2 - Starting to do work
>
> 10292 [9] INFO Program chunk 2 - Finishing work
>
> 10292 [9] INFO Program chunk 3 - Starting to do work
>
> 15299 [9] INFO Program chunk 3 - Finishing work

However, I can't figure out how to maintain that using 'normal' async methods.

For instance, trying to do this:

```
private static ILog s_logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Program");

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BasicConfigurator.Configure();

    var task1 = DoSomeWork("chunk 1");
    var task2 = DoSomeWork("chunk 2");
    var task3 = DoSomeWork("chunk 3");

    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
}

static async Task DoSomeWork(string chunkName)
{
    using (log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Stacks["NDC"].Push(chunkName))
    //using (log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks["NDC"].Push(chunkName))
    {
        s_logger.Info("Starting to do work");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        s_logger.Info("Finishing work");
    }
}
```

Shows them all starting "normally", but when the task completes on a different thread, the stack is lost (I was hoping the log4net.LogicalThreadContext would be TPL-'aware' I guess).

> 234 [10] INFO Program chunk 1 - Starting to do work
>
> 265 [10] INFO Program chunk 2 - Starting to do work
>
> 265 [10] INFO Program chunk 3 - Starting to do work
>
> 5280 [7] INFO Program (null) - Finishing work
>
> 5280 [12] INFO Program (null) - Finishing work
>
> 5280 [12] INFO Program (null) - Finishing work

Outside of adding a new TaskContext (or the like) to log4net, is there a way of tracking this kind of activity?

The goal is really to do so with the async/await syntax sugar - either forcing some kind of thread affinity or doing things like keeping a concurrent dictionary around keyed by task are likely workable options, but I'm trying to keep as close to the synchronous version of the code as possible. :)

Comment: FYI, I recently discovered that Microsoft fixed `CallContext` in .NET 4.5 RTW to work with `async`. So log4net's NDC and other solutions using `Logical*Data` will work as expected with `async` methods (on .NET 4.5 only).

Comment: I'm not sure it's a problem coming from the logical thread context. The log4net implementation looks wrong to me because parent and child thread share the same stack. The child should receive a clone of the parent stack so that if the parent modifies the stack it doesn't perturb the child...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There isn't a good story for `async` logical call contexts right now.

<strike>`CallContext` can't be used for this. The logical `CallContext` doesn't understand how `async` methods return early and resume later, so it will not always work correctly for code that uses simple parallelism such as `Task.WhenAll`.</strike>

***Update:*** `CallContext` was updated in .NET 4.5 RTW to correctly work with `async` methods.

I looked into log4net; `LogicalThreadContext` is documented as using `CallContext`, but there was a bug that made it use the non-logical contexts (fixed in their SVN on Feb 2, 2012; the current 1.2.11 release does not include that fix). Even when it's fixed, though, it'll still not work with `async` (because the logical `CallContext` doesn't work with `async`).

When I need an `async` logical call context, I make a class that contains the context data and keep all of my `async` methods in a functional style as instance members of that class. This is *certainly* not an ideal solution, but it's a dirty hack that works.

In the meantime, please upvote the [suggestion that Microsoft provide some mechanism for this](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2698599-add-an-async-compatible-logical-call-context-).

P.S. A concurrent dictionary keyed by `Task` won't work, because `async` methods are not necessarily running tasks (i.e., in your example code, at the `using` statement, `Task.CurrentId` would be `null` because there is no task actually executing at that point).

And thread affinity has its own problems, too. You actually end up needing a separate thread for each independent asynchronous operation. Bye-bye, scalability...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - for the concurrent dictionary approach, I wouldn't be using async methods at all, but instead would be 'explicitly' using tasks (so, what you can already do in VS2010/.NET4).  Kind of wish I could just attach data to a Task (well, without subclassing and making my own) and get the 'current task context' similar to HttpContext.Current, although I haven't really thought that through, either. :)

Comment: I see. Well, if you want to attach data to a `Task` (other than `AsyncState`), you could use [Connected Properties](http://connectedproperties.codeplex.com/), but IMO it's just as easy to use `ConcurrentDictionary` for this scenario.

Comment: @StephenCleary Stephen Toub replied to your linked post on User Voice saying that your initial information was outdated and CallContext is appropriate for async/await.

Comment: @Lex: Updated. Note that `CallContext` - while it *can* be used - still won't solve the problem.

Comment: It looks like this is finally fixed in log4net 1.2.14 - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28868941/2144

Comment: @Eric Pohl, I'm on 1.2.15 and LogicalThreadContext still doesn't persist with async/await.

Comment: I'm using log4net 2.08 and the LogicalThreadContext properties are indeed carried across different threads when the "async" keyword is used.