# Log4net LogicalThreadContext not working as expected

Tags: c#, asynchronous, log4net, async-await

I've been trying to use Log4nets LogicalThreadContext to provide context to each of my log entries. My application uses async/await quite heavily, but from reading various articles the LogicalThreadContext should work properly with asynchronous code, from .NET 4.5 onwards. I'm using .NET 4.5.1 and log4net 2.0.3

I came across a great [article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) by Stephen Cleary about logging and the .NET CallContext, and as a result I decided to take his code and adapt it to use log4net, in an attempt to see if there was something wrong in my code that may have been causing the issue.

Firstly, I ran Stephens code exactly as is and got the expected output like so

```
Main 1: <SomeWork>
Main 1 A: <MoreWork>
Main 2: <SomeWork>
Main 2 A: <MoreWork>
Main 1 A: </MoreWork>
Main 1 B: <MoreWork>
Main 2 A: </MoreWork>
Main 2 B: <MoreWork>
Main 2 B: </MoreWork>
Main 2: </SomeWork>
Main 1 B: </MoreWork>
Main 1: </SomeWork>
```

Next, I modified the code to use log4net rather than Stephens custom `MyStack`

```
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
    private const string StackName = "test";

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        using (LogicalThreadContext.Stacks[StackName].Push("Main"))
        {
            Task.WhenAll(SomeWork("1"), SomeWork("2")).Wait();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task SomeWork(string stackName)
    {
        using (LogicalThreadContext.Stacks[StackName].Push(stackName))
        {
            Log.Info("<SomeWork>");
            await MoreWork("A");
            await MoreWork("B");
            Log.Info("</SomeWork>");
        }
    }

    private static async Task MoreWork(string stackName)
    {
        using (LogicalThreadContext.Stacks[StackName].Push(stackName))
        {
            Log.Info("<MoreWork>");
            await Task.Delay(10);
            Log.Info("</MoreWork>");
        }
    }
}
```

I expected to get a similar output as before, but instead this time I got the following

```
Main 1: <SomeWork>
Main 1 A: <MoreWork>
Main 1 A 2: <SomeWork>
Main 1 A 2 A: <MoreWork>
Main 1 A 2 A: </MoreWork>
Main 1 B: <MoreWork>
Main 1 B: </MoreWork>
Main 1 B B: <MoreWork>
Main 1 B B: </MoreWork>
Main 1 B: </MoreWork>
Main 1: </SomeWork>
Main 1: </SomeWork>
```

Notice the separate logical thread contexts start to overlap. This indicates to me the log4net isn't using the CallContext correctly but from everything I can find it looks like they've already fixed any issues around this.

Has anyone else encountered this or know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like log4net *still* does not work with `async` logical stacks.

The log4net NuGet package 2.0.3 is log4net 1.2.13 (the current version as of today). There was a bug reported ([LOG4NET-317](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-317)) because at that time `LogicalThreadContext` used `CallContext` instead of `LogicalCallContext`.

The [current version of `LogicalThreadContext`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/LogicalThreadContext.cs?revision=1539082&view=markup) does use `LogicalThreadContext`, but the [current version of `ThreadContextStacks`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/log4net/Util/ThreadContextStacks.cs?revision=1539082&view=markup) does *not* correctly use an immutable stack.

Interestingly, [Andrew Arnott correctly pointed out in the original bug report that they had to use an immutable stack](http://logging.markmail.org/thread/q3bogptirf32g77r#query:+page:1+mid:ouwfvitbd5bjjgz4+state:results). In 2011.

Feel free to write up a minimal repro and report it as a log4net bug. The key scenario is using the stack within multiple tasks that are combined using `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I thought this may be the case.

Comment: If you do write up a repo, please post a link here. Otherwise, I'll probably get around to it later this week.

Comment: I am having a .Net 4.0 service with log4net 1.2.13 and i am using the Microsoft package Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

Comment: Hello, @rudimenter. If you mean "it doesn't work", the reason is that the logical call context in .NET 4.0 is not fully compatible with `async`/`await`. You need to update to .NET 4.5 to get an `async`-compatible logical call context.

Comment: @StephenCleary Sorry i wanted to edit the comment but got "interrupted" but you basically answer my question. Thanks

Comment: @StephenCleary I am just reading in the Blog from you that you should only save immutable data within the LogicalThreadContext. This means log4net would also not work in .net4.5 because it actually safes its own dictionary within LTC under a magic key and just updates the values of its own dictionary. It calls LogicalSetData only once on creation time. It means LogicalThreadContext would also not work as expected because values set in childtasks could be overwritten in the parenttask (instead of creating a new one). I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @rudimenter: Yes; that's what I say in my answer above: "the current version of `ThreadContextStacks` does not correctly use an immutable stack."

Comment: @StephenCleary Ah ok. It was a misunderstanding. I thought ThreadContextStacks uses something else but i just see it is using the LogicalThreadContext internally. Cheers

Comment: It looks like this issue was fixed in 1.2.14: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-455

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this on one of our projects. This should fix it: https://github.com/apache/log4net/pull/12.

The code basically obeys to the `shallow-copy-on-write` and `immutable` rules described by @StephenCleary and the accompanied test case withstands the `Task.WhenAll` scenario.

Comment: The long awaited next release of log4net (1.2.14) has landed: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/release-notes.html. It contains a fix for the problem described in this thread.

Comment: The first link after 'This should fix it' leads to a Page Not Found error. FYI