# Log4net LogicalThreadContext parameter's value is null after await

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, owin, log4net, middleware

I have this code snippet to an owin middleware

```
    public class SetCurrentActionInfoMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{

    public SetCurrentActionInfoMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) :
        base(next)
    {
    }


    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["prop1"] = "some text";  

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

And inside my web api action I do some logging like this

```
Log().Info("Start getting CurrentBusiness info");
```

But when I check my database the value is coming as null, but if I use GlobalContext I will get it

My question  is whey when I use LogicalThreadContext I get null ?

Comment: What version of log4net are you using?

Comment: I am using version  2.0.7

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316743/log4net-logicalthreadcontext-not-working-as-expected

Comment: @WahidBitar Thanks alot

Comment: @WaddahRasheed Did you ever resolve this problem? I'm seeing the same thing with log4net 2.0.8.

Comment: @JohnnyHK No I have resolved another way . You know I am using asp.net web api with OWIN middleware  and the way I have resolved is to assign values to my log4net properties inside web api filter instead of OWIN middleware.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I'm having the same issue as you, have managed to find any solution? I am using log4net 2.0.8 and .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: @ohabbers I changed my approach to set the LogicalThreadContext properties in my logger wrapper class instead of in middleware.