# How to add some per-request (OWIN) value to log4net context?

Tags: owin, log4net

I try to create OWIN(IIS Hosted) middleware that will ensure that all log4net events will have a particular property (`CorrelationId`) assigned per-request.

I tried to:

1. Use following middleware and use `IOwinContext`.

**It works** only when appender batching size is to 1. Otherwise, the whole batch of events is assigned the same `CorrelationId`.

```
public class CorrelationIdMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public CorrelationIdMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next): base(next){}

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {            
        correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        context.Set("CorrelationId", correlationId);
        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Middleware was paired with log4net active property:

```
public class CorrelationIdActiveLog4NetValue
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
        if (context != null)
        {
            var value = context.Get<string>("CorrelationId");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return value;
            }
        }

        return "N/A";
    }
}
```

2. Use LogicalCallContext.

   `var stack = log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Stacks["CorrelationId"]
   using (stack.Push(correlationId))
   {
       log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CorrelationIdMiddleware))
           .Info("TEST MESSAGE");
       await Next.Invoke(context);
   }`

It worked for the message I produced in the middleware itself, but not when I logged from controllers.

For comparison, in Serilog such middleware code works universally in every case(ASP.NET core):

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("BayCorrelationId", context.TraceIdentifier))
{
    await next(context);
}
```

Comment: Please show some code how you are using `CorrelationIdActiveLog4NetValue`.

Comment: It is just `log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["CorrelationId"] = new CorrelationIdActiveLog4NetValue()`. It does not work, because its `ToString()` method is called only when batch is about to be sent and by that time `IOwinContext` from previous requests is long gone.

Comment: That's indeed the issue with the first approach. There's already a post about the issue with your second attempt (also without a solution) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316743/log4net-logicalthreadcontext-not-working-as-expected.  The only way to get something similar running is by setting `log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["CorrelationId"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` in `OnActionExecuting` of an `IActionFilter`.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I already "solved" the issue by using implementing action filter. I am not yet sure if combining two approaches (action filter and middleware will guarantee that all code between will log with `CorrelationId` as needed)